# GEB + Spock: No signature of method

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am trying to write a simple test with GEB and Spock. Following is the Page and Spec test:

Page

```
import geb.Page

  class DashboardPage extends Page {
  static url = "?root=dashboard"
  static at = { pageTitle.text() == "Dashboard Content Area" }

  static content = {
    pageTitle(wait: 25) { $("div#content-view-title>h1") }
    leaderBoardPeriodCombo { $("#leaderboardPeriod") }
    //manualsMenu { module(ManualsMenuModule) }
  }

  def selectLeaderBoardPeriod(periodValue) {
    leaderBoardPeriodCombo.value(periodValue)
  }
}
```

Spec Test:

```
import geb.spock.GebSpec
import pages.DashboardPage

class LeaderboardSpec extends GebSpec {
  def "change LeaderBoard type value"() {
    when: to DashboardPage
    then: at DashboardPage
    when: DashboardPage.selectLeaderBoardPeriod("monthly")
    then: at DashboardPage
  }
}
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: static pages.DashboardPage.selectLeaderBoardPeriod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [monthly]
Possible solutions: selectLeaderBoardPeriod(java.lang.String)
    at specs.LeaderboardSpec.change LeaderBoard type value(LeaderboardSpec.groovy:13)


Results :

Tests in error:
  LeaderboardSpec.change LeaderBoard type value:13 MissingMethod No signature of...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

The signature of the selectLeaderBoardPeriod it have a parameter. I tried to define explicitly the type as String but i am getting the same error.

Can someone spot what i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: When you call `DashboardPage.selectLeaderBoardPeriod("monthly")` you expect to execute a static method while `def selectLeaderBoardPeriod(periodValue)` is defined in non-static scope.

Comment: This makes completely sense. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spec needs to be something like:

```
class LeaderboardSpec extends GebSpec {
    def "change LeaderBoard type value"() {
        when:
        def page = to DashboardPage

        and:
        page.selectLeaderBoardPeriod("monthly")

        then:
        at DashboardPage
    }
}
```

Comment: Another hint for the OP who is, like he said in his previous question, a Geb newbie: `to SomePage` already performs an `at` check and only if that check is true it returns a page instance. This is what Tim uses here and why he does not need an extra check at the beginning (`page` would be `null` if `at` had failed). So even if you do not want to assign the page to a variable and use it later in the test as shown here, you can still just use `expect: to MyPage` instead of `when: to MyPage; then: at MyPage`. Check out the [Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/) for more details.